# InstallShield - Save registry only if 64-bit operating system

Tags: installshield

I am making an InstallShield *Basic MSI* setup. It is outside of Visual Studio. I want to save a registry value only if it is 64 bit OS. See image:[image]

How do I configure the setup project to save a registry value only if it is 64-bit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new component using Setup design option in left navigation pane. In Condition field, enter **VersionNT64** for 64-bit operating system condition. Now back to registry option, check 'View Filter' option in upper middle section and select the component which you had created. Now create whatever registry you want to create. It will be created only on 64-bit OS at the time of installation.

Answer (score 1):

You can condition the registry creation based on the **VersionNT64** property.

The installer sets the **VersionNT64** property to the version number for the operating system **only** if the system is running on a 64-bit computer. The property is undefined if the operating system is not 64-bit.